# Does JFrog Arifactory Open Source include file transfer?

Tags: artifactory

We are currently using JFrog Artifactory Open Source 7.41.7 to store a number of artifacts.  We would like to transfer these artifacts to our company's JFrog Artifactory Enterprise Plus 7.55.8.  In trying to install the **data-transfer** user plugin as described at [Step 1 - Set Up the Source Instance for Files Transfer](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/step-1-set-up-the-source-instance-for-files-transfer), I get the following errors which suggested that Artifactory file transfer isn't available in JFrog Artifactory Open Source:

```
~$ jf rt transfer-plugin-install source-server --home-dir=/opt/jfrog
18:55:38 [Info] Installing 'data-transfer' plugin...
18:55:38 [Warn] The server response: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 500,
      "message": "This REST API is available only in Artifactory Pro (see: jfrog.com/artifactory/features). If you are already running Artifactory Pro please make sure your server is activated with a valid license key.\n"
    }
  ]
}
18:55:38 [Warn] (Attempt 1) - Failure occurred while sending POST request to https://glz8plpsc.pok.ibm.com:8443/artifactory/api/plugins/reload
18:55:38 [Warn] The server response: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 500,
      "message": "This REST API is available only in Artifactory Pro (see: jfrog.com/artifactory/features). If you are already running Artifactory Pro please make sure your server is activated with a valid license key.\n"
    }
  ]
}
18:55:38 [Warn] (Attempt 2) - Failure occurred while sending POST request to https://glz8plpsc.pok.ibm.com:8443/artifactory/api/plugins/reload
18:55:39 [Warn] The server response: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 500,
      "message": "This REST API is available only in Artifactory Pro (see: jfrog.com/artifactory/features). If you are already running Artifactory Pro please make sure your server is activated with a valid license key.\n"
    }
  ]
}
18:55:39 [Warn] (Attempt 3) - Failure occurred while sending POST request to https://glz8plpsc.pok.ibm.com:8443/artifactory/api/plugins/reload
18:55:39 [Warn] The server response: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 500,
      "message": "This REST API is available only in Artifactory Pro (see: jfrog.com/artifactory/features). If you are already running Artifactory Pro please make sure your server is activated with a valid license key.\n"
    }
  ]
}
18:55:39 [Warn] (Attempt 4) - Failure occurred while sending POST request to https://glz8plpsc.pok.ibm.com:8443/artifactory/api/plugins/reload
18:55:39 [Error] executor timeout after 3 attempts with 0 milliseconds wait intervals
```

Can someone confirm that JFrog Artifactory Open Source does not include file transfer as I've been unable to find any official statement of the features included in JFrog Artifactory Open Source?

If file transfer is not included as I suspect, is there a way to transfer artifacts **with their properties** from JFrog Artifactory Open Source to JFrog Artifactory Enterpeise Plus short of using the JFrog API or CLI to download artifacts from JFrog Artifactory Open Source, upload the artifacts to JFrog Artifactory Enterprise Plus, search artifacts in JFrog Artifactory Open Source for their properties, and finally set the artifact properties in JFrog Artifactory Enterprise Plus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to install an Artifactory user plugin on Artifactory OSS.

Artifactory OSS does not support installing user plugins, including the data-transfer plugin. Please contact JFrog sales to obtain a temporary Pro license.

For more info:

- [Artifactory Comparison Matrix](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-hosting-models-documentation/artifactory-comparison-matrix)